# Вывод миниатюры страницы WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте! Пишу свою тему на ВП. Нужно получить ссылку и вывести картинку, которая задается к странице. Насколько я понимаю, get_the_post_thumbnail_url() работает только в цикле и подходит к постам.
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция [get_the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) работает где угодно. Имеет два аргумента

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post, $size );
```

Первый - id поста.

Чувствую, есть непонимание, поэтому поясняю: пост и страница - это одно и то же в WordPress.

Comment: Добавил id, заработало. Спасибо!